# How to access network shares as a different user

Tags: windows, network-shares, domain

I have several network shares mapped to users on the login.script (Windows 2003 Domain controller)

I am trying to access a certain share with administrator rights.

The problem is that if I try to connect according to the answer : https://superuser.com/a/291131/88758 it tells me that the network share is already using other credentials, and I need to disconnect them first.

- Does that apply to ALL the shares? (I have about 8 mapped)
- I am trying to access a single share/folder with admin rights, and leave the rest connected as regular user - is that even possible?