# How to Password Protect USB Ports?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, usb, port

Is there a way to Password Protect the USB Ports in Windows 8 so that every time a USB is inserted a prompt comes out asking for a password before it can be used on the PC ? Is this possible without 3rd party software ? Can it be done in Windows Group Policy ? If not i would like to hear suggestions about good 3rd party software.

[image: USB Port]

---

#### Group Policy Solution

In Computer Configuration → Administrative Templates → System  Removable Storage Access when enabling the policy `All Removable Storage Classes: Deny All Access`, my PC stops unauthorized access for all USB ports and all removable storage. That is what I actually wanted, but it is annoying that every time I want to use a USB port I have to open my Group Policy and disable the Removable Storage policy. A Prompt asking for administrator rights or a password prompt would be much better.

Comment: Someone asked the same question here with a link for how to do it with Group Policy: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-security/how-can-i-password-protect-my-usb-port/4acdf6a0-9058-4093-b80e-0dff468779dd   and here are some 3rd party options: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fF_hE09sB8E  or  http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Lockdown/USB-Port-Locked.shtml  Iam unsure how well these solutions will work on Win8 though, I don't have a copy to test with.

Comment: could you split this out into two separate questions - for windows and linux?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I think it is the same in Linux, you can not do it without third party software

Comment: The methods for each would be different.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek ok i deleted from my question the Linux OS, after i find out how to do it the best way in Windows i will ask the same question for linux.

Comment: Group policy should satisfy your request, as it's linked to your username/password. Have a look at http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows8-disable-usb-policy.htm on what options you have to play with... If you actually want a popup asking for a password, you'll need 3rd-party software but I don't know how effective they are.

Answer (score 2):

*(I know this is an old thread, but I feel that the information below is useful for anyone who is trying to accomplish what the OP asks.)*

The following solution works in a domain environment and does not require the use of any third-party utilities.

Setting the Removable Storage Access policy under *Computer Configuration* applies the policy to the whole computer. By setting the same policy under *User Configuration* instead, you can apply the policy to a group of users (using security filtering), including your non-administrative account.

You can then leave the administrative account out of the security-filtered group.

When you need to access the drive, you will need to switch users (log in to Windows with your unrestricted administrative credentials).

You can launch explorer.exe as a separate user, but it requires making some registry changes. Please review [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/290940/how-to-launch-windows-explorer-with-the-privileges-of-a-different-domain-user) for details.

*NOTE: The above is written for domain environments, where the policy can be applied per-user using domain group policy management. You can apply group policy on a per-user (or per-group) basis in a standalone environment, but it is more difficult.*

Answer (score -1):

TrueCrypt is the best tool to password protect your  USB , it works fine for windows 8 for me but i heard there are some  issues

[Here is a link](http://www.programmerfish.com/password-protect-your-flash-drive-using-truecrypt/) which explains how to use this tool, procedure with screen shots

Note: TrueCrypt works fine for windows 8 for most of  the users(including me) but i have heard that computers having UEFI BIOS have some issues with TrueCrypt For Windows 8

Comment: This is about password protecting the USB, but I am asking about password protecting the port where the USB is inserted into the PC.